# Length of a security token

Tags: security, token, access-token

I'm using security tokens to create not guessable URLs like this (16 bytes, hex)

```
http://example.com/something/private/b5f8c21a628e12b39786fb8ef9561d31
```

The token is something like a shared passwords: Who knows the URL is allowed to access the resource.

**How many bytes** should a secure random value have to be appropriate for secure URLs?

Comment: Are you paying the URLS by their lenght :-)? Probably not... Then 32 hex characters as you are using them are perfect! :-)

Comment: What is the purpose of this token/URL?

Comment: If your PRNG is good this should be long enough. I strongly recommend using a well seeded crypto PRNG.

Comment: I'm using and trusting Javas SecureRandom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ended up with a 64 Bit random value which is encoded as url-safe Base64. The possibility to guess the correct token is `1 / 2^64` what is equal to `1 / 18446744073709551616`. This is a pretty impressive number and it would be nearly impossible for an attacker to find the correct token with http requests.

URLs look like this now: `http://example.com/private/1oWYPiqO81k/`

Comment: Adding this link for future reference, as it is somewhat related and good to know in this context: http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/

Comment: Also this table about the entropy contained in different encodings https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Random_passwords

Comment: Might be enough if the information isn't anything sensitive. OWASP, even in 2006 recommended **minimum** of 128-bit session identifiers. I'm just letting you know, because your answer has been cited in questions asking about what's good token length, and 64 bit is not enough unless you're fine with the possibility that someone will guess them.

Comment: Python implementation can be done using [secrets.token_urlsafe()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well all applications depend on a [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) at some point.  After all this is a session id or csrf token value.  The importance here is that it doesn't matter how long the value is if the attacker has 100 years to break it.  Now 100 years is a long time,  but you should strive for your designs to last this long.

The main difference in security between a cookie and your value is that the cookie expires and changes for every use.  But in all reality this value should be avoided at all costs.  If this is used for authentication,  then rely on the session id,  that's why its there.  Don't roll your own session.

Answer (score 0):

10 unicode characters URLs for example, are pratically impossible to guess because tokens are 160 bits long and thus there are 2 ^ 160 different possible URLs. However you shouldn't rely on something like that for security, but on classical login and auth

Comment: Building a url from arbitrary unicode characters sounds like a bad idea. Practically I wouldn't go beyond about 64 different chars like they are used in base64.